# JavaScript detecting play/pause keyboard (virtual) key

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, media-player, dom-events

By accident, I just pressed the play/pause (<kbd>▶/❚❚</kbd>) button on my keyboard (the button just above <kbd>Num Lock</kbd> on [image: Lenovo keyboard], while playing a YouTube video in a tab that was not focused. To my massive surprise, the YouTube video paused immediately.

Now, I tried looking up how this works, but I was not able to find anything on the internet explaining how a keypress can be detected for keys like this. I tried running `onkeydown = function(e) {console.log(e)}` in my console, but pressing the play/pause button did not trigger any event. Also, https://keycode.info/ did not give me any help with this either. I did find http://www.kbdedit.com/manual/low_level_vk_list.html which lists a whole lot of 'virtual key codes', which does include `VK_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE`, which is probably the key I am pressing, but I did not find any way to trigger an event in JS with this.

Now I do want to specify that this functionality does not seem to work in Firefox, only in Chrome (as far as I've tested). It might be something that's still experimental, but I am really interested to hear what system YouTube uses to capture this event, even when the tab is currently not opened (Chrome wasn't even focused at the moment)

PS: I experienced this on Ubuntu 18.04; I'm not sure if this will work on Windows, for example.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/02/media-session

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Google Chrome Media Session Samples](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/media-session/audio.html):

```
/* Media navigation Action handlers */

    navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('previoustrack', function() {
      console.log('> User clicked "Next Track" icon.');
    });

    navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('nexttrack', function() {
      console.log('> User clicked "Next Track" icon.');
    });

    navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('play', function() {
      log('> User clicked "Play" icon.');
      // Do something more than just playing audio...
    });
```

These chrome apis are availble on chrome 57+, and Firefox 82+

Comment: Looks like, as of last October, Firefox now also supports it: https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_mediasession. I think this means the code you gave now works exactly like this on Chrome, FF and Edge, right?

Comment: Yeah you're right. Just updated the answer

Comment: I don't have media keys anymore so I can no longer test this easily

Answer (score 6):

Chrome is responsible for that (Hardware Media Key Handling), for more details check out chrome://flags/#hardware-media-key-handling

Also here is link that contains docs and demo: https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5639924124483584

Comment: Is there any online resource that gives me a starting point to figure out how to use this?

Comment: Yea, i found this:
https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5639924124483584

You have some links to docs there, but i'm still not sure what is your overall goal.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like it has a clear demo, I can work with that. I am just looking to see if I can build similar functionality to the one in YouTube. Could you edit your answer to include that link, so that I can mark it as accepted?

Comment: Sure, it's done. Yea you can definitely build a similar functionality with this. :)